# How to calculate the count of users each month based on the previous count with MongoDB query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to calculate the accumulated count of users based on the count value from the previous month.

The results array should look like this:

```js
RESULTS  [
  { count: 1, accumulatedCount: 1, month: 12, year: 2021, verified: true },
  { count: 3, accumulatedCount: 4, month: 1, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 3, accumulatedCount: 7, month: 2, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 1, accumulatedCount: 8, month: 3, year: 2022, verified: true },
]
```

Right now, my aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```js
const results = await this.accountModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          ...match,
          createdAt: {
            // $gte: range.from,
            $lte: range.to,
          },
        },
      },
      { $unwind: '$organizations' },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            month: { $month: '$createdAt' },
            year: { $year: '$createdAt' },
            verified: '$organizations.verified',
          },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          month: '$_id.month',
          year: '$_id.year',
          count: 1,
          verified: '$_id.verified',
        },
      },
    ]);
```

and it returns this:

```js
RESULTS  [
  { count: 1, month: 10, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 4, month: 7, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 3, month: 2, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 1, month: 3, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 1, month: 12, year: 2021, verified: true },
  { count: 2, month: 1, year: 2022, verified: true },
  { count: 1, month: 8, year: 2022, verified: true }
]
```

Basically, I would need to `reduce` the count based on the prev and current value.

I couldn't find any suitable options in the MongoDB docs.

I use "mongodb": "3.6.3".

Comment: Why 3 code snippets if all fail?

Comment: to embed the code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      docs: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$docs",
          "initialValue": {
            accumulatedCount: 0,
            data: []
          },
          "in": {
            accumulatedCount: {
              "$sum": [
                "$$this.count",
                "$$value.accumulatedCount"
              ]
            },
            data: {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value.data",
                [
                  {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        accumulatedCount: {
                          "$sum": [
                            "$$this.count",
                            "$$value.accumulatedCount"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs.data"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs.data"
    }
  }
])
```

Group all documents, in an array. Loop over the array using `$reduce`, keep the running sum of counts, and the updated list of documents with `accumulatedCount`, in two variables. Finally, unwind the list and bring the docs to the root.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v7CXp1_tI09)

You can just add the new stages in your pipeline.

Comment: thank you it works. Is there also a way to conditionally use `$gte: range.from`?